# Cannot add component into a widget in the qt designer

Tags: qt, pyqt, designer

I used Kali Linux.
When I attempt to drag some components to my widget, it failed for unknown cause and my cursor became the style of "Forbidden", I cannot drag any component into my widget.

Did anyone know how to solve it ?
How can I add component into my widget.

Comment: Sorry but your question is too vague. What components are you talking about? What widget? Can you please [edit] your post and provide some screenshots (or screencast) of your attempts? Also, what PyQt (and Qt) version are you talking about? You wrote "I ***used***", what does that past tense mean?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English , for your questions: 1. I'm using Kali linux; 2. the 'widget' I mean is Main Window for Qt5 Application; 3. As far as I know ,  the basic way to add component into my ui file is dragging the component qt designer offered in the left side but when I drag any component in the left side, my cursor icon becomes in the shape of  'forbid' and I failed to add any component into my window

Comment: Don't worry about your English skills, we know that most of people here doesn't speak it as their mother tongue (I'm one of them). That said, sorry but your didn't answer most of my questions, so please take your time in order to do it.

Comment: Can you tell me about my mistake while explaining ? I didn't know which point I didn't explain enough [/cry]

Comment: 1. Qt features the possibility of using *plugins*, so, besides the *basic* Qt widgets there are many other "extended" widgets that could be available: we don't know if you're trying to add a basic one (aka: those provided in the QtWidgets module) or not; 2. For a similar reason, we cannot be completely sure if you're actually trying to add widgets to a native QMainWindow or another one; 3. I asked for some screenshots or a screencast (a video captured from your computer); 4. You didn't specify the exact versions of Qt and PyQt (their minor version numbers don't usually match); 5. "used" when?

Comment: Kali linux is designed for one specialized use case and is not really usable as a general distro. I don't know if that's causing your specific problem, but I'd switch to a more general purpose Linux distro.